# How to center crop an image (<img>) in fluid width container

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, fluid-layout, fluid-images

How do I get an image to stay centered when its fluid width (percentage based) container is too small to show the whole image?

[image]

**How can I center the image inside it's container**

This means it should show the middle of the image instead of the sides when container is too small.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

### When It Works

You might have a container that holds some content such as two `<div>`s that are 50% wide each, sitting next to each other. For this example, we can illustrate just one child of the container:
[image]

We'll name outer rectangle `.container`, the inner rectangle `.content` and the image `img`. This arrangement is perfectly fine, *as long as `.content` is always wider than `img`.*

### When It Breaks

Since we're dealing with percentages and probably working with a responsive design, this may not always be the case. If `.content` is ever thinner than `img`, cropping will occur:

[image]

### The Problem

If the most interesting part of `img` is in the center, we need to get the browser to crop both edges evenly - leaving the best part of it visible, no matter what width of `.content` is.

[image]

### The Solution

Fortunately, a solution is possible. Even better, no extra markup is required.

```
.content {
    width: 90%; /* or whatever is required */
    text-align: center; /* ensures the image is always in the h-middle */
    overflow: hidden; /* hide the cropped portion */
}

img {
    position: relative; /* allows repositioning */
    left: 100%; /* move the whole width of the image to the right */
    margin-left: -200%; /* magic! */
}
```

Comment: Hi Bryce, excellent tutorial, it works for me, but I want to stop by and ask, how does this works? I don't really understand how. Maybe someone can enlighten me.

Comment: @BryceHanscomb In dev tools "IE9" I'm not seeing the issue... but in a stock VM from modern.ie Win7/IE9 I am seeing the issue. I assume the real IE9 would be trusted over the simulator?

Comment: @BryceHanscomb Change width to anything other than 200px. Should it not be centered still? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the requirements... http://imgur.com/A2JAqRr

Comment: Note: inside a `table-cell` you need to center the `img`, not the `.content`.

Comment: @isal Alternative that works for both: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673900/how-to-center-and-crop-an-image-to-square-with-css

Comment: This is weird, it only works above a certain size. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ha65p/17/) and resize the pane up and down.

Comment: you are star, looking for this answer from good few days ...   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159476/how-to-create-focus-point-for-each-image-in-image-slider-for-full-screen-display

Comment: add this
` img { height: 100% } `

Answer (score 20):

For new browsers, you can translate it

```
figure{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img{
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,0)
}
```

To support IE8, you can still use the technique presented above by @BryceHanscomb.

```
.no-csstransforms figure img {
    left: 100%; /* move the whole width of the image to the right */
    margin-left: -200%; /* magic! */
}
```

Comment: To support older versions of Safari add vendor prefixed transform too:
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,0);

See this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29864790/why-on-safari-the-transform-translate-doesnt-work-correctly

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it supports large size images.

Answer (score 1):

If you are anticipating that the image to be displayed will be so much longer than the display container, setting left: 100%; and margin-left: -200%; (from Bryce's answer) might not be enough to get the center part of the image. Just put a bigger percentage for both. Make sure that the other is half of the other though.

```
left: 500%;
margin-left: -1000%;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but the solutions here didn't help me (because I'm displaying inside a table and because I wanted the image to change without having to scale it manually every time as the image was sent by clients)

Here's what I found, much more effecitve and easier :

```
img {
 object-fit: cover;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 }
```