# Responsive Background Video

Tags: css, html

I am looking to make my video background like this:
http://www.teektak.com/

The issue I'm having is that my video is responsive, but it is fixed to the left. I can't figure out for the life of me how to make it so that it centers horizontally to the window when adjusted.

Here is a link to the test site to see what I am talking about: https://robotplaytime.paperplane.io/

HTML

```
<body>
    <video poster="images/robotPlaytimeVideo.png" id="bgvid" autoplay loop muted>
        <source src="images/robotPlaytimeVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
video { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: -100;
    background: url(../images/robotPlaytimeVideo.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to center a <div> on a page vertically and horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally)

Comment: Wrapping it in a div and using that css still anchors the video to the top left corner. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You probably don't need the div, just center the video as if it were a div

Comment: Tried that, didn't change the responsiveness. It's still anchored to the top left corner.

Comment: Tried what? There are 16 different methods/answers on the linked page.

Comment: Well I tried the first solution (and checked out the others) and it fixed vertical centering, so thanks! But the video is still anchored to the left, so now I need to figure out why it won't center horizontally: https://robotplaytime.paperplane.io/

Comment: The video is trying to maintain aspect ratio, unless you want to distort the video or crop the video, it will have white space when centered...

http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/h99y1cvh/1/

Comment: I don't have a problem with it maintaining the aspect ratio, so how it is set right now is ok. I am just trying to figure out how to make it horizontally center when the width is adjusted. See this example: http://www.teektak.com/. Right now not having any white space is how it should be. It is fine if the video overflows. It just needs to be centered to the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these CSS rules to your body (the video's parent container):

```
text-align: center; /* ensures the image is always in the h-middle */
overflow: hidden; /* hide the cropped portion */
```

Add these CSS rules to your video:

```
display: inline-block;
position: relative; /* allows repositioning */
left: 100%; /* move the whole width of the image to the right */
margin-left: -200%; /* magic! */
```

Most of this was pulled directly from Bryce Hanscomb's answer to another similar question: [How to center crop an image (<img>) in fluid width container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247356/how-to-center-crop-an-image-img-in-fluid-width-container)

Here's a jsfiddle just in case:
http://jsfiddle.net/pLj0gcpu/

(Note that the markup and styles in this fiddle were pulled from your given URL)

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. Your answer is close enough to what I had. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

To get the video to take the full size of the screen:

```
video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Doing this gives me white space. My current code gives me the full screen affect, but it is anchored to the top left. The affect should be similar to this: http://www.teektak.com/. For example when you resize the previous links width it recenters the video. When you resize the height it vertically aligns the video in the middle.

Comment: Is your parent container set to position: relative; ?

Comment: Nope, but I just tried it and it left me with white space. Here is the site: https://robotplaytime.paperplane.io/

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna center something horizontally responsively, then do

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Note, you will need to set a "position" as well