# How to make background with video and navbar over the video?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a full screen video as a background and upon that I want to add bootstrap navbar and in the center of the screen, I want to add one logo. And there will be one footer after the video section.It should be responsive. I tried but the video is not getting responsive. SO can you please help me out.

Comment: Add your code, or else we can't help you out

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411762/responsive-background-video