# CSS transform porperty Safari

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get following output (a large slash line between two numbers):

[image]

Following code works on Firefox and Chrome but doesn't work on Safari. Would there be any workaround for that?

Here's the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="top">4</div>
    <div class="bottom">15</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.top {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.bottom {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 70px;
  position: relative;
  width: 28px;
}

.bottom:before {
  border-left: 1px solid;
  content: "";
  height: 66px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -35px;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform-origin: left top 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

**JSFiddle Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/pg4sxrc1/

Comment: You can refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29864790/why-on-safari-the-transform-translate-doesnt-work-correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain versions of Safari still require the use of the `-webkit-` prefix for `transform` and `transform-origin`, try adding the following definitions to your `.bottom:before` CSS:

```
-webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: left top 0;
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pg4sxrc1/1/)